# How can I add orientDB repository in maven?

Tags: maven, orientdb

I am trying to add orientdb repo in maven following these [instructions](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Download#last-snapshot-compiles-and-pass-all-the-test-cases). My pom.xml looks like that:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>orient-test</groupId>
  <artifactId>orientdb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
                <distribution>repo</distribution>
                  </license>
  </licenses>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orient-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
    <artifactId>blueprints-orient-graph</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
  </dependency>
  <repository>
    <id>sonatype-nexus-releases</id>
    <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </repository>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

but I keep getting these errors:

> Missing artifact
> com.orientechnologies:orient-commons:jar:1.6.1-SNAPSHOT
>
> Missing artifact
> com.orientechnologies:orientdb-core:jar:1.6.1-SNAPSHOT
>
> Missing artifact
> com.tinkerpop.blueprints:blueprints-orient-graph:jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT

Also  is underlined in red, but there is no error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by adding 1.6.3 version of orient-commons and oriented-core. For the blueprints-orient-graph you should I add the following code snippet:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

instead of what I have in the original question

Answer (score 1):

Don't use old snapshot but replace "1.6.1-SNAPSHOT" with just "1.6.3"

Comment: And for the blueprints-orient-graph what should i use?

Comment: Depending on SNAPSHOTs for released artifacts is REALLY odd!

Comment: Starting from 1.7 we'll link only BP final releases.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the snapshot versions for all the dependencies are available in SonoType Server (some of them are wiped out regularly): https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orient-commons/
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-client
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-core
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blueprints-orient-graph/

Answer (score 0):

I have just added following dependency in my **pom.xml** file & everything works like a charm.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```